# Dojo DnD acceptance of outside objects

Tags: dojo, drag-and-drop

Is it possible to code a Dojo DnD target to accept external objects, such as files or folders from a file explorer?  Windows Explorer, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it, because it will be the browser that will receive the DnD event...
At best you can count on a plugin or extension to handle it, like the excellent [DragDropUpload](http://www.teslacore.it/wiki/index.php?title=DragDropUpload) extension does for file upload fields in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of file explorer are you talking about? From what I can recall you'd be lucky to get dnd working properly even for table rows, the api is a pain in the @$$.