# Drag and Drop of file upload in DOJO

Tags: dojo, drag-and-drop

Is there an option in DOJO where files can be uploaded by Drag and Drop from desktop to the browser?

Answer (score 0):

No I dont believe so. As outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162733/dojo-dnd-acceptance-of-outside-objects) and [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/community/#nabble-td470785) its not really possible to do without using a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but still one of those posts being found by google easily. For those interested how to do this:

- Have a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18212438/2299448)
- Dojo overview of [how to use its Uploader](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/form/Uploader.html) (styled as a button)
- Use `addDropTarget` to link a dropArea for that uploader ([for HTML5-enabled browsers](https://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.8/dojox/form/uploader/plugins/HTML5) -- see also first link))
- To make the drop target visibly react to drag events, I had to connect directly to browser events [like `ondragenter` or `ondragleave`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondragleave.asp) (see code snippet below)

```js
createUploader: function() {

  // ... define uploader and droptarget

  d_on(this.dropArea, "dragover", d_lang.hitch(this, this.dropAreaOver));
  d_on(this.dropArea, "dragleave", d_lang.hitch(this, this.dropAreaLeave));
  d_on(this.dropArea, "drop", d_lang.hitch(this, this.dropAreaLeave));
}

dropAreaOver: function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    domClass.add(this.dropArea, "dropAreaOver");
},


dropAreaLeave: function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    domClass.remove(this.dropArea, "dropAreaOver");
}
```