# Dojo Uploader with Drag and Drop

Tags: file-upload, dojo, drag-and-drop, uploader

I am trying to recreate this example in my project, to add the drag and drop feature to the dojo uploader:

> http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/form/tests/test_Uploader.html

Copying the exact same code in jsfiddle or in my application the line

```
if(uploader.addDropTarget && uploader.uploadType=='html5'){
```

returns undefined for addDropTarget and iframe for the uploadType. 
I tried it with various browsers, and even added force: html5 in the uploader but nothing changed.

Please, note that everything works ok except from the dnd.

I am using dojo 1.8.1.

Comment: Can you paste your code ? Did you set the file input with multiple="true" ? Did you require the html5 plugin ? Did you try to set the uploader option "force" to "html5" ? What browser are you using ?...

Comment: Yes I added that and I required the html5 plugin as well. Everything works regarding the file selection and upload part.
I am just trying to enable the dnd feature. Tested with chrome and firefox.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Can you post your code ?

Comment: Philippe, I am using the exact same code as the one in the link.

Comment: And what browser are you using ? Because if it works in the link and not in your code, then there must be a difference somewhere...

Comment: I tested with both Chrome and Firefox. I don't know if they are using another version of the uploader in the link, as they are pulling the dojo.js from a nightly build

Comment: Yeap. That's it. They are using a different build of dojo.js. I added the nightly build path in jsfiddle and it worked. However, is there a workaround?

Comment: Hmm... I know things are much improved in 1.9... I'll try to see if I can make it work in a 1.8.1 fiddle...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In dojo 1.8, the uploader is not yet fully AMD compliant. So, in order to make the example from the trunk tests work in 1.8, you need to create the uploader programmatically using the dojox.form.Uploader constructor rather the required AMD module. As follows :

```
<form method="post" action="UploadFile.php" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <fieldset>
        <legend>DnD Test</legend>
        <input class="browseButton" id="uploader"/>
        <input type="submit" label="Submit" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" />
        <div id="files" data-dojo-type="dojox/form/uploader/FileList" data-dojo-props='uploaderId:"uploader"' ></div>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<div id="dropTarget">Drop files here !</div>
```

And in the javascript :

```
require([
    'dojo/parser',
    'dojo/dom',
    'dijit/registry',
    'dojox/form/Uploader',
    'dojox/form/uploader/FileList',
    'dojox/form/uploader/plugins/HTML5',
    'dojo/domReady!'
], function(parser, dom, registry, ready){

    var dropTarget = dom.byId('dropTarget'), uploader;

    parser.parse().then(function(){

        // You need to use dojox.form.Uploader, as in dojo 1.8, 
        // the module is not fully AMD compliant yet.

        uploader = new dojox.form.Uploader({
            name:'uploadedfile', 
            label:'Select Some Files',
            multiple:true, 
            force:'html5'
        }, 'uploader');

        uploader.startup();

        if(require.has('file-multiple')){
            console.debug("Adding a new drop target");
            registry.byId('uploader').addDropTarget(dropTarget); 
        }
    });
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/psoares/6r2jZ/

Comment: Great! However, now the uploader button does not work. Any clues?